# mysql query that return number of credits

Tags: mysql

there are three tables (students,grade,course)

```
table1: students 
Name  ,  Id
Joseph,  1
David ,  2

table2: grade
Id(fk of students.id) , Course(fk of course.courseName),Grade
1 , math101 , A
1 , math103 , B
1 , eng201 , A
2 , eng201 , B
2 , math103, B

table3: course
courseName , credits
math101 , 3
math103 , 4
eng201  , 3
```

I want to get each Name with total number of credits that he/she earn

```
QUERY...
result -->

ID,NAME,TotalCredit
1,Joseph,10
2,David,7
```

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: not exactly same as homework
made my own and will manipulate on hw

Comment: And i dont know why people dis grade this question

Comment: Not the downvoter, but it's because you didn't show what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   SELECT s.id, s.name, sum(c.credits)
     FROM students as s
LEFT JOIN grade as g on s.id = g.id
LEFT JOIN course as c on g.course = c.courseName
 GROUP BY s.id, s.name
```

Comment: A group function/single value function/scalar function cannot work without the `GROUP BY` clause :)

Comment: @Tiny it can, but I missed a `GROUP BY` in this case. Edited! Thank-you